# iPad Camera Connection Kit to Talk to Non-Storage USB Devices?

Tags: ios, ipad, robotics

I am doing some experimenting with robotics and have a USB servo controller that I would like to connect to my iPad. Does anyone know if it's possible to access USB devices such as this on the iPad?  And if so, what mechanisms can I use to talk to it? The servo controller's manufacturer has made the controller's protocol open so if I can talk to it, I should be able to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is most likley you will not be able to control the servo DIRECTLY form the iphone.

A servo is controller by some sort of ["servo-controller"](http://proto-pic.co.uk/pololu-micro-serial-servo-controller-assembled/)

[image]

And this server is controlled using an RS232 interface that accepts commands in some sort of characters or bits.

So I found [this rs-232 app that looks interesting on app-store](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/rs232-terminal-for-direct/id348887344?mt=8) but not sure how to use it?

[But you can buy cables like this for iphones and ipads](http://www.robotshop.com/redpark-iphone-db9-rs232-serial-adapter.html) Keep in mind that RS232 and TTL use different voltages.

[image]

Instead of getting more hardware for the iPhone / iPad, use the built in [Bluetooth and the SPP (Serial Port Interface) with some code and this excellent piece of kit (i use it often it great)](http://shop.kula.org.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=2_6&products_id=9) This just needs some power (it runs on TTL@9600bps not RS232 so check for voltage compatibility) you pair it and get a proper virtual COM port to communicate over Bluetooth without any special programming!  You need to check if you iOS allows you to use SPP Bluetooth Profile. A lot of older iOS devices do not allow much over Bluetooth- so you might need a cable.

[image]

- [There is nice project here on how to use serial on iOS](http://devdot.wikispaces.com/Iphone+Serial+Port+Tutorial)
- And here is way to use [Bluetooth HID included in most iPhones / iPad with a clever device that re transmits it using Bluetooth SPP](http://serialio.com/support/BlueSnap/BlueSnapBridgeSetup.php) .. hehehe - Suck on that Steve
- And here on [spark fun is a ready product.](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) whatever you type on the iPhone (or using a programme that pushes characters to Bluetooth HID) which get converted to TTL...

Comment: Thanks, I am using the Pololu Mini Maestro 24-Channel USB Servo Controller which does have a serial connection but I was hoping that I could use USB.  Guess I will need to use the serial... Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ExternalAccessory.framework`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008235) and its APIs.

There's also a brief guide on [External Accessories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ExternalAccessoryPT/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009502).

Comment: This only applies to MFi-compliant devices that expose a communication protocol. The Camera Connection Kit does not, so it can't be used in this fashion.